# Visual Studio Add-In for Grouping Files

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I used to have a nice little Visual Studio Add-In that allowed me to group files by simply right clicking on them.

It used to modify the csproj file in the background and add the relevant  attributes.

I have just rebuilt my machine and can't find the add-in anywhere. So just wondered if anyone knows of a similar one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ok, found it in the end.

Link is here if anyone is interested...
http://mokosh.co.uk/vscommands/

Comment: Gone, there is an updated version for VS2013 at the [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SquaredInfinityJarekKardas.VSCommandsforVisualStudio2013).